PS2EXE errors on Win11 24H2
I'm running into an issue with a PS2EXE generated exe on Win11 24H2, that works on Win11 23H2.
It's a very simple script to install an encrypted app package (eappx).
Add-AppxPackage -Path "config\AppName.eappx"
When I run the PS2EXE generated exe on Win11 23H2, it installs as expected. However, when I try the same binary in Win11 24H2 I get the following error:
"The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception."
I can install the eappx file directly on the PS CLI (24H2) using the same command 'Add-AppxPackage -Path "config\AppName.eappx"' and this installs as expected. This suggests the eappx file is not the cause of the issue.
I tried installing a different simple package .appx to prove it's not the eappx file. This appx will install successfully using the App Installer (double click in file explorer) and also via PS CLI. However, it fails with the same error when using the PS2EXE generated binary.
Finally, I tried running other PS commands in the PS2EXE binary to see if everything was impacted.
Running the script/exe below displays the date/time correctly for both calls but the "Add-AppxPackage" throws the above exception.
Get-Date
Add-AppxPackage -Path ".\config\test.AppxBundle"
Get-Date

When I search on the "The type initializer for '' threw an exception." error, I see suggestions that a DLL may be missing.
But I have no way of finding out what is causing the issue.
I'm wondering if I need to install something on 24H2 for P2EXE generated code to still work, but I have no idea what.
I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue.
Many thanks

What happens when you use the fullpath: Add-AppxPackage -Path "<fullpah>\config\AppName.eappx"?

@iRon Exact same result with the full path

See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-24h2#known-issues

@jdweng Any item in particular I should be looking at on this page? I'd checked this page recently and did not find anything that seemed to cover this issue.

I would file a inquiry with Microsoft.  I suspect it is with a driver as stated on page.

Report problems here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-24h2#report-a-problem-with-windows-updates

@jdweng Thanks. Sent in feedback to MS on this. I'll see what comes out of it.
